# Load test client-side rendering page

Tags: javascript, client-side, load-testing

I've built a client-side rendering web app using VueJS. Now I want to make a load test for my page. The problem is, test tools such as [Loader.io](http://laoder.io) or [Siege](https://github.com/JoeDog/siege) just grab a very tiny HTML piece of my page (this HTML contains scripts that needed to download then execute by client after). Therefore, the test was completed so quick and it does not reflect the performance of my site.

I thought of simulating a headless browser but it seems to be impossible to do a `load` test due to performance limitation of my desktop.
Could you guys give me any suggest? Thank in advance!

Comment: have you considered the built in Dev tools for your browser to check all of the page processing, compositing, drawing...?   After all, it will not get any faster than with one browser, one tab on one host.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any load testing tools capable of executing client-side JavaScript without causing overhead (you can use [LoadRunner's TruClient protocol](https://community.hpe.com/t5/LoadRunner-and-Performance/TruClient-in-the-world-of-Load-Testing/ba-p/5927581#.WJhf8OLR_mg) or [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) with the [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverTutorial/), but they are very resource intensive as they basically kick off a browser instance per virtual user)

But you could do something else. Despite the fact the load testing tools neither actually render HTML page nor execute JavaScript, they can mimic HTTP requests which are driven by the JavaScript. See [How to Load Test AJAX/XHR Enabled Sites With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-ajaxxhr-enabled-sites-jmeter) article for implementation examples.

Also it would be good idea to use a tool like [YSlow](http://yslow.org/) while your main load test is running in order to assess rendering speed and detect slowest scripts or images.